# Error making a GUI... UnboundLocalError: variable 'clicks' reffered to before assignment

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, runtime-error

When I run this code I get this error:  UnboundLocalError: variable 'clicks' reffered to before assignment. don't know what to do from here. If it helps, I am running python 2.7.5

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
clicks = 0
def press():
        clicks += 1

def displayclicks():
        print clicks

root = Tk()
root.title("Test GUI")
root.geometry("200x100")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
Label(app, text="press the button!").grid()
clicks = 0
x = Button(app, text="BUTTON", command=press)
x.grid()
y = Button(app, text="Print clicks", command=displayclicks)
y.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this all of your code?  Does your error message give you a line number to look at?

Comment: it is reffering to 'click += 1' and this is all of my code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change a global variable, you need to explicitly refer to it. Since your method `press()` is adding to the global variable `clicks`, you need to use the `global` keyword to refer to it:

```
clicks = 0

def press():
    global clicks # make sure I am referring to the global
                  # variable, since I am going to modify it.
    clicks += 1
```

In your method `displayclicks()` you don't have to do this because you are simply printing the value, not modifying it.

Comment: Importing is an odd way to describe this.

Comment: "bring it into scope"?

Comment: i forgot about using the global keyword. i think i need to use that somewhere but the way you say to use it doesnt work.

Comment: Its not working? Maybe because you are resetting it later down in your code?